# Raspberry Pi and FFMpeg live streaming video to backend Node.js server, but how do I deliver it to the front end?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, rtsp

I'm attempting this setup to live stream video from a Raspberry Pi to a publicly available website, and from the backend server using Node.js and Express, I would like to serve it to the front end with minimal latency available to many viewers (will be hosted somewhere like Netlify to handle distribution).

WebRTC is too complex for my use case and timeframe. HLC appears to have too high a latency as I need <4s consistently. I would like to something compatible with Node.js. I am a beginner in this domain, familiar only with general programming and web development.